# Kivy text input auto scroll to top of text

Tags: python, kivy

How do you get a kivy textinput loading from the top , currently if i put more text in it than it can contain it scrolls to the bottom instead of the top

[image: example image]

```
    TextInput:

            text:root.text
            readonly: True
            background_color:  [0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 0.8]  # should root.color
            font_name: 'C:\kivy_venv\Graphics\GIL_____.TTF'
            foreground_color: [1, 1, 1, 1]
            font_size: self.height*0.2
            background_normal: "C:\kivy_venv\Graphics\jetload##%^%#%#%% .gif"
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want new text to be inserted at the top of the `TextInput`?

Comment: Hi John, I have added a picture to illustrate the issue better, basically when i load a string into text input and its more lines  than the vertical boundary it loads from the last line cutting off the top lines need to reverse it if possible

Comment: You can move the cursor up using   text_input.cursor=(0,0)

Comment: sorry that does not solve because you still have to place a crusor

Comment: The solution proposed by @FadiAbuRaid is correct. It worked for me, the text_input.cursor=(0,0) must be defined after loading the text to the text_input

Comment: An alternative solution is to use text_input.do_cursor_movement("cursor_home", True)